# Combine values by key in single array

Tags: php, arrays, sum

Nothing really does exactly what I want to achieve. I have the following array:

```
Array(

[0] => Array
    (
        [chicken] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cheese] => 9
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [marinade] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [cookbook] => 7
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [chicken] => 11
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [cheese] => 6
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [marinade] => 12
    )

)
```

I want to sum all values by their key. If the key is multiple times in the array, like `chicken`, I want to sum the values.

```
array
(
[chicken] => 18,
[cheese] => 16
... etc

)
```

Comment: Show your attempts and what went wrong.

Comment: My attempts did not sum up the values, but only kept the last/highest value, hence that code is useless. If any code I made would be usefull to post, I surely would have

Comment: It's still encouraged on this site to show your attempt.  (Especially when dealing with topics like this that would have been covered in many other similar questions)

Comment: I understand, and I normally would. The problem is that I have been staring myself blind on this code, and am currently trying another approach, wherefor I deleted the previous code. I will update when i got a new attempt

Comment: I  added an answer that should work, but for future, provide your code attempts, even if wrong.

Comment: Thanks you in advance! I will try your answer as soon as possible when I fixed some probems I made in the meanwhile...guess I need a break

Comment: `$result = array_map(function($x) { return array_sum((array) $x); }, array_merge_recursive(...$array))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'd first need a loop to iterate through the first array to get the second-level arrays.  Then you can get the current key and value from each of those arrays, summing the values in a new array associated by the key.

```
// where the sums will live
$sum = [];

foreach($array as $item) {
    $key = key($item);
    $value = current($item);
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $sum)) {
        // define the initial sum of $key as 0
        $sum[$key] = 0; 
    }
    // add value to the sum of $key
    $sum[$key] += $value;
}
```

Comment: you code could be more fast if you use `isset()` instead of  `array_key_exists`

Comment: I highly doubt you'd find a noticeable real world difference between the two in modern versions..

Answer (score 1):

Here simple example i hope it's help you.

```
$result = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value) 
{   
     $valueKey = key($value);
     $result[$valueKey] += $value[$valueKey];
}
```

Comment: you must know that $value in this case  is an array too and edit your answer according to this...